# How to calculate possible missing characters?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, char

I'm trying to get possible missing characters e.g:

input --> `aa??bb` there should be possible characters `aaaabb` & `aaabbb` & `aabbbb` so the result would be 3, Also `?a?` would be 1.

Note:
`aababb` would be wrong, because it's not a right path for alphabet.

I'v done some code here but i couldn't get the perfect result yet.

may someone help me?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = input.nextLine();
    int possibleAlphabet = 1, oldPossibleAlphabet = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        oldPossibleAlphabet = 0;
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        if (s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z'  || s.contains("?")) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '?'){
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (s.charAt(i - 1) == '?' && s.charAt(i + 1) == '?')
                        oldPossibleAlphabet++;

                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.print( " ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        possibleAlphabet += oldPossibleAlphabet;
    }
    System.out.println(possibleAlphabet);
```

Comment: @MuratK. i forgot to mention that, it would be in the same path, e.g `acb` is wrong `abc` is right.

Comment: why `aababb` is not a possible case ?

Comment: @mustabelMo because a came before b, like one before two!

Comment: good to know, because in your question nothing refered to that order

Comment: @mustabelMo thanks, i updated that.

Comment: Can '?' chars occur not in a row? For example, do we need to consider combinations like 'ab??cde???z'?

Comment: yup we need to consider `ab??cde??z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my code

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abc??cde???g?"; // Example
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        int length = arr.length;

        // Init value for count, start and end
        int count = 0;
        char start = 'a';
        char end = 'a';
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == '?') { // We found a question mark
                boolean foundEnd = false;
                int total = 1; // Currently the total of question mark is 1
                for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) { // Count the total question mark for our method and the end character
                    if (arr[j] != '?') { // Not question mark
                       end = arr[j]; // Update end;
                       i = j -1;
                       foundEnd = true;
                       break;
                    } else {
                        total++;
                    }
                }

                if (!foundEnd) { // Change end to start in the case our question mark continue to the end of string
                    end = start;
                }
                // Start to counting and reset end to 'z'
                int result = countPossibleCharacters(total, start, end);
                if (count > 0) {
                    count *= result;
                } else {
                    count += result;
                }
                end = 'z';
            } else {
                start = arr[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The total is : " + count);
    }

    /**
     * Count the possible characters
     * @param total the total question mark
     * @param start the character in the left side of question mark
     * @param end the character in the right side of question mark
     * @return
     */
    static int countPossibleCharacters(int total, char start, char end) {
        if (total == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (total == 1) {
            return end - start + 1;
        }

        if (total >= 2) {
            int count = 0;

            /**
             * We have a range of characters from start to end
             * and for each character we have 2 options: use or don't use it
             */
            // We use it, so the total of question mark will be decrement by 1
            count += countPossibleCharacters(total - 1, start, end);

            // We don't use it, so the range of characters will be decrement by 1
            if (start < end) {
                count += countPossibleCharacters(total, ++start, end);
            }

            return count;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Rules apply in my code**

1. All characters in string are lowercase
2. Character on the left side must be lower than character on the right side
3. If we have a question mark in the beginning of string, we'll loop from 'a' to the next non question mark character
4. If we have question mark in the end of string, we'll replace it with previous non question mark character

Comment: `?a?` the total is 26 ?

Comment: For the first question mark, we only have 1 character 'a' is suit with it
. In the second question mark, it must be a -> z = 26 character
. The total is 1 * 26 = 26

Comment: it should be one case only, not 26 then ?

Comment: Check my rule: If we have a question mark in the beginning of string, we'll loop from 'a' to the next non question mark character. In this case, the next non question mark character is 'a' (I wrote all the rules in the end of my answer)

Comment: Do we have another rule to apply for ?a?

Comment: Take a look on  Sample Input:
aa??bb,
aaccbb,
?a?,
a??a


Sample Output:
3,
1,
1,
1,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156005/discussion-between-hung-vo-and-android).